# PHP - Quicker way to do this?

Tags: php, performance

```
foreach(self::getGroups() as $group) $group_ids[] = $group->getId();
```

Is there a better, cleaner and more efficient way to do that?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the only other way of doing that is with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and it's not necessarily  any quicker or better:

```
function get_id($group) {
  return $group->getId();
}

$group_ids = array_map('get_id', self::getGroups());
```

Comment: Ah ok. Thought as much. 


Thanks very much! :-) You've just confirmed that I wasn't being an idiot :P